# How do I get latest dependencies using yarn command on NextJS

Tags: material-ui, next.js, yarnpkg

I was looking at some examples in Material-UI for NextJS because I am getting the warning @material-ui/styles@4.10.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.8.0".When I searched in their repo, they suggested to use the latest version to solve the problem, and I found the following command in their json file
`dependencies": { "@material-ui/core": "latest", "clsx": "latest", "next": "latest", "prop-types": "latest", "react": "latest", "react-dom": "latest" }`

I have been trying to get the latest version using different commands like yarn add @material-ui/core@latest and @material-ui/core-latest but it does not work. It might be simple but I didn't find the correct syntax, so I am asking here.

How do I get the latest dependencies using the yarn commands?